# How to set taxes following in OpenERP?

Tags: odoo

How to set taxes following in OpenERP?
PRIVATE LIMITED FORMULA FOR INVOICE.

```
PRODUCT NAME     QUANTITY       RATE    AMOUNT.
Sugar            22000KG        21.00   4,62,000/-
                                        ________
(Gross Price including
With Profit margin)                     4,62,000/-
BASIC EXCISE @12% (462000*12%)            55,440/-
 EDU.CESS@2%         (55440*2%)            1,109/-
 SEC.HIGHER EDU CESS@1%                     5,54/-
 (55,440*1%)                                
                                        ________
                                        5,19,103/-
VAT @4% (519103*4%)                        20764/-
ADD VAT@1% (519103*1%)                      5191/-
                                        _________
                                    5,45,058/-
```

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the Tax from View you have child Tax , just set your child tax over their in sequence you want to add their but yes do into expect the sum total after some tax applied then  grand total after other total applied.

Thank You

Comment: Hello, thnkzZ . But with your answer help i just tried but i m getting solution. The calculation till the VAT is perfect but problem occurred at ADD VAT@1% this 1% calculate on total amount till the VAT@4%.PlzZ help me.

Comment: use base code tas and also choose which is base and which are following